# Ruby SSL Error working with Evernote API (Mac, El Capitan)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, evernote

Trying to get [the basic ruby Evernote client app](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-ruby) working.

I got [my developer token](https://sandbox.evernote.com/api/DeveloperToken.action) and followed the readme in the sample app.

> 1. Open sample/client/EDAMTest.rb
> 2. Scroll down and fill in your Evernote developer token.
> 3. On the command line, run the following command to execute the script:
>
>    `ruby EDAMTest.rb`

Simple. But I'm getting this SSL Error.

/Users/james/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)

Tried a few things with brew and rvm.

```
$ rvm osx-ssl-certs status all                
> Certificates for /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem: Up to date.
> Certificates for /etc/openssl/cert.pem: Up to date.
```

Full trace.

```
/Users/james/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
  from /Users/james/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `block in connect'
  from /Users/james/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:73:in `timeout'
  from /Users/james/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect'
  from /Users/james/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
  from /Users/james/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
  from /Users/james/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1375:in `request'
  from /Users/james/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1398:in `send_entity'
  from /Users/james/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1186:in `post'
  from /Users/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/evernote-thrift-1.25.1/lib/thrift/transport/http_client_transport.rb:58:in `flush'
  from /Users/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/evernote-thrift-1.25.1/lib/thrift/client.rb:41:in `send_message'
  from /Users/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/evernote-thrift-1.25.1/lib/Evernote/EDAM/user_store.rb:23:in `send_checkVersion'
  from /Users/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/evernote-thrift-1.25.1/lib/Evernote/EDAM/user_store.rb:18:in `checkVersion'
  from sample/client/EDAMTest.rb:39:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up patching it by turning off verification.

```
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

Still open to any better ideas.